# Import csv :mysql datetime query

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import csv file to mysql where datetime values field after importing is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and csv file is like this. 19/05/2014 14:42:13. I am using c# windows application to import the files.can you please help me how to get the exact datetime into mysql from csv file.

```
string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'I:/finaltest12.csv' INTO TABLE tickets  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (SiteId,DateTime,Serial,DeviceId,AgentAID,VehicleRegistration,CarPark,SpaceNumber,GpsAddress,VehicleType,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleColour,IssueReasonCode,IssueReason,NoticeLocation,Points,Notes) ";
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(strLoadData, conn);
```

Comment: you need to convert `19/05/2014 14:42:13` to `Y-m-d H:i:s` before importing you can do it directly in CSV using the colum format

Comment: Thanks Abhik I tried like this but no luck still.....`  string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'I:/kiran/final test/finaltest12.csv' INTO TABLE tickets  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (SiteId,DateTime,Serial,DeviceId,AgentAID,VehicleRegistration,CarPark,SpaceNumber,GpsAddress,VehicleType,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleColour,IssueReasonCode,IssueReason,NoticeLocation,Points,Notes)  SET DateTime = STR_TO_DATE( DateTime, '%a %b %d %k:%i:%s UTC %Y') "`

Comment: No the data does not look correct it should be `date_format ( str_to_date('19/05/2014 14:42:13','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: you can leave out the date_format()

Comment: I tried this but still displays zeroes.. but  just changed '19/05/2014' to column name. DateTime  and it still does that.